# Easiest way to sandbox an user

Tags: permissions, users, access-control

I'd like to sandbox a user so that they can only read files under `/media/shared/somefolder`. What's the easiest way to accomplish this? Users/groups? ACL? AppArmor?

Some context: Plex Media Server is a media server with a web interface that allows you to browse all of your server's file-system searching for media files. I don't want users to be able to navigate my whole filesystem, not even in read-only mode! So I need to restrict the `plex` user.

Comment: You can probably configure your plex server or if not, write or modify an apparmor profile for your plex server, depends on if you are using Ubuntu (Apparmor) or Fedora (selinux) or ...